# How to add timestamps fields and _id into nested schema by default

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have a correct schema `User` where fields `_id`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` are written by default. But in schema `Message` it doesn't work.

```
export type UserDocument = HydratedDocument<User>;

@Schema({ timestamps: true, versionKey: false })
export class Message {
  @Prop()
  content: string;
}

@Schema({ timestamps: true, versionKey: false })
export class User implements UserInterface {
  @Prop()
  name: string;
  @Prop()
  email: string;
  @Prop([{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message' }])
  messages?: Message[];
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

Here is my function of message creating:

```
async createMessage() {
    const user = await this.userModel.findById('63ee4fc044d93a4f6bebf934');
    user.messages.push({ content: 'a' });
    return await user.save();
  }
```

And error is:

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ content: 'a' }" (type Object) at path "messages" because of "BSONTypeError"
```

But this snippet works fine:

```
async createUser(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<CreatedUserDto> {
    return this.userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { name: createUserDto.name },
      createUserDto,
      { upsert: true, new: true },
    );
  }
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed id, correct implementation:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';
import { UserInterface } from '../interface/user.interface';

export type UserDocument = HydratedDocument<User>;

@Schema({ timestamps: true, versionKey: false })
export class Message {
  @Prop()
  content: string;
}

export const MessageSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Message);

@Schema({ timestamps: true, versionKey: false })
export class User implements UserInterface {
  @Prop()
  name: string;
  @Prop()
  email: string;
  @Prop({ type: [MessageSchema], default: [] })
  messages?: Message[];
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```